# Qualcomm Atheros AR9565 Device Driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, atheros

I've seen the other helps offered for this problem, but I run into errors left and right.  I'm pretty new to Linux so please be patient with me. Here are the steps I've taken:

I've already installed the linux generic build essentials

I tried to install the package from http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2

I typed:
sudo wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2

I get an ERROR 404: Not Found

There also seems to be errors in trying to locate my compat-drivers...
one set of instruction said to type:
cd compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-s

I am told No such file or directory.

Comment: And what is the problem you're trying to solve exactly? BTW, 404 means it doesn't exist. Probably a good thing because if you don't know what you're doing, better explain first and wait for solutions than to download random things for who know what purpose.

Comment: The driver for your device *ath9k* is included in all recent Ubuntu versions. If it is not working as expected, something else is wrong. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath9k`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Katie, in terminal enter `rfkill list` please edit to include the output

Comment: My wifi randomly started working again days later...not sure what changed, but I'm glad it did